# Pandas: Read_csv, commas missing

Tags: python, pandas, csv

If I open my csv file

https://github.com/JulianLeGrid/Bach

with an editor everything is fine, but when I import it via pandas `read_csv`

```
t1= pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\UNI\Bachelor\Hotmaps\2010Profiles\ninjatemp.csv')
```

most of the commas in the temperature column are missing (as you can see it in the picture).

[image]

Do you know what went wrong here?

Comment: how does your csv look like?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to have a comma delimiter and commas as part of the fields. Proper quoting can salvage that, but that can be complicated too if some fields have quotes. Is the delimiter something you have control over, use something less common like `'|'`

Comment: @Ade_1 you can find the csv here:
https://github.com/JulianLeGrid/Bach

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue: `import pandas as pd

DATA = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JulianLeGrid/Bach/main/ninjatemp.csv"
dataf = pd.read_csv(DATA)
`

Comment: I don't find comma in the temperature column in your csv file itself. Please recheck.

Comment: Note: If you `print(t1)` it will not display the commas, just the data formatted as a pandas table.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your original CSV file is missing commas in temperatures. Anyway, if your float numbers have a separator `,` use use the `decimal` parameter in your call

`t1 = pd.read_csv('ninjatemp.csv', sep=',', decimal=',')`

Comment: Thank you all for your response. I found the mistake. It didn't have to do with pandas but with the way libreoffice calc transformed my data!